# Lying in some situation to avoid a sin is halala or haram

Tags: lying

So during my exams my friend ask me to help by telling answers.
Inorder to not do sin I tell them I don't know the answer and act like I didn't do my exam well .
So is lying in this situation haram or halal.
I don't give the straight answer that I  will not help because they tell bad about and not  be friends anymore .

Answer (score 1):

It's not good/halal. Scolars point out actually two circumstances in which lying is halal:

- If a lie contributes to peace or harmony.
- If it is clear that the person to whom you lie has bad intentions towards God and His Will, and/(or?) is fighting against those who follow Him.

https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/81140/cases-in-which-lying-is-permitted-2/

You had better told him the truth (i.e. that you don't want to encourage him to cheat).

Comment: "If a lie contributes to peace or harmony." Could you please explain? A lie out of courtesy or submission can do all sorts of harm. Maybe this is not the place and it should be asked as a question of its own right?

Comment: I have put two of three aspects of the cited scolarly answer (read the link) under one point. We need not tell the truth if it may offend someone and there is no need to correct her or him (pointing out a sin or transgression).

Comment: Cheating is a minor sin; it is not a reason to lie for "harmony", because the request may need correction, but it is no reason for treating him as an enemy and/or notorious transgressor. In this sense, it should be the best choice to answer saying the truth.

Comment: "Cheating is a minor sin", yes, obviously there are bigger sins. And I'm not really sure what "cheating" is. Selling lead for gold, that would be cheating in my view. Saying "this man is after your life and you better kill him before he kills you" is not covered be the mild term of "cheating".

Comment: @GyroGearloose here, it's cheating in an exam, in my view lesser compared to selling lead for gold. Not a big thing, but still not entirely honest, and not of the category "Something the man tells his wife to please her" or "to bring peace between the people", see for explanation in the longer hasan version of Abu Dawud.

Comment: As of the question above, the sin is even lesser, it is about *not* cheating in an exam.